# Analyzing Trade Data in R: Determining Market Share and Trade Trends

Tags: r, statistics, aggregate, subset

## Introduction

I have some basic trade data in a very large data set. I'd like to use R to compare market share, by country of export, of a single good (say, 'spoons') into a country (say, USA). A sample data set in a data frame called 'trade' would look like

```
shipment <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) #transaction ID number for a shipment of spoons
date <- as.Date(c("2006-08-06", "2006-07-30", "2006-04-16", "2006-02-05", "2007-01-10", "2007-09-22", "2007-10-15", "2007-03-30")) #date of shipment
value <- as.integer(c(1208, 23820, 402, 89943, 643, 45322, 25435, 1455)) #value of the shipment, in USD
country <- c("France", "Spain", "France", "Belgium", "France", "Belgium", "Spain", "Belgium") #the country where the export originated from
trade <- data.frame(shipment, date, value, country)
```

I want to aggregate the transaction-level data and analyze it at the country level to determine how the spoon industry has evolved over time--that is, which countries were players in any given year.

This is the code I devised (with the help of Matthew Lundberg), but it seems quite long and clumsy so I'm wondering if there is any easier way.

## R Code

```
agyr <- aggregate(value ~ format(date, "%Y") + country, data=trade, FUN=sum) #to get value of exports by country and year
colnames(agyr)[1]="year" #rename the 'year' variable

#reshapes from long to wide
agyrw <- reshape(agyr, 
  timevar = "year",
  idvar = c("country"),
  direction = "wide")

#sums total trade value, by year
sum2006 <- sum(agyrw$value.2006) 
sum2007 <- sum(agyrw$value.2007)

#creates new variables of market share, by year
agyrw$share.2006 <- agyrw$value.2006 / sum2006
agyrw$share.2007 <- agyrw$value.2007 / sum2007

#formats the market share variable to only 4 decimals places
agyrw$share.2006 <- format(round(agyrw$share.2006, 4), nsmall = 4)
agyrw$share.2007 <- format(round(agyrw$share.2007, 4), nsmall = 4)

#reconverts the market share variable back into numeric so that it can be ordered
agyrw$share.2006 <- as.numeric(agyrw$share.2006)
agyrw$share.2007 <- as.numeric(agyrw$share.2007)

# sorts the data frame by 2007 and 2006 market share
agyrw <- agyrw[order(-agyrw$share.2007, agyrw$share.2006), ]

# displays the data frame 
agyrw
  country value.2006 value.2007 share.2006 share.2007
1 Belgium      89943      46777     0.7796     0.6421
5   Spain      23820      25435     0.2065     0.3491
3  France       1610        643     0.0140     0.0088
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong but I am pretty sure it will be downvoted and closed. It is not reproducible (you some variables, then try to access different) and show serious lack of understanding what is going on. You try to compare characters with dates, subset by column when you want by row...

Comment: I hope it doesn't get downvoted and closed, as I'd really love to learn how to do those things in R. I've struggled for weeks trying to figure it out on my own, but to no avail. I provided a sample data set and tried to be as clear as possible on what I want to do. The big flaw in my question is the lack of good example code, but, that's kind of a Catch 22 as that's why I'm here.

Comment: I suggest you start with fixing sample data. Then you can see what is the difference between `trade[1]` and `trade[1, ]`. Then you can try to use `as.Date("2006-12-31")` instead of `"2006-12-31"`. That's for starters.

Comment: The sample data frame was fixed by Steven Beaupre.

Comment: You should break the task up.  This looks like multiple questions, especially the numbered list at the end.

Comment: @MatthewLundbergh I simplified the question to focus on only the first part.

Comment: If you upload some toy data from http://www.wto.org/english/res_e/statis_e/statis_e.htm, close to your original data, you'll get very constructive answers.

Comment: The WTO toy data is a good suggestion, but I'm wondering if there is an easy way in R to provide compact sample data output, kind of like the reverse of the c() command for inputting vectors.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as "too broad". After the edit, it is quite specific: how to calculate market share for a good in the sample data set, and then code for how to do this in R is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the exports by country and year, `aggregate` is handy:

```
aggregate(value ~ format(date, "%Y") + country, data=trade, FUN=sum)
##   format(date, "%Y") country value
## 1               2013 Belgium 89943
## 2               2006  France  1208
## 3               2009  France   402
## 4               2008   Spain 23820
```

You can then take this and produce the share per year.  It will help to rename the first column above:

```
ag <- aggregate(value ~ format(date, "%Y") + country, data=trade, FUN=sum) 
names(ag)[1] <- year

ag$share <- ave(ag$value, ag$country, ag$year, FUN=function(x) x/sum(x))
ag
##   year country value share
## 1 2013 Belgium 89943     1
## 2 2006  France  1208     1
## 3 2009  France   402     1
## 4 2008   Spain 23820     1
```

Note that the years are unique in your example, so each country gets 100%.